# Spring JPA partial update by non primary key causing issue(Closed)

Tags: spring-boot, spring-mvc, jpa, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

My entity has 15 fields, where Id is the UUID. I want to update them by non-primary key(field2 is unique).

Entity

```
Id
field1
.
.
field15
```

MyRepository

```
public interface myrepo extends JpaRepository<mymodel, UUID> {

  Optional<MyModel> findByField2(String value);

}
```

My service

```
    MyModel MyModel =
        repo
            .findByField2(val)
            .orElseThrow(
                () ->
                    new RunTimeException());

// mapstruct to override the non-null fields
MyMapper.update(request,myModel);

------------> Upto this step everything is fine

repo.save(myModel) ---> This step is getting failed with the following exception.
```

Stack trace:

```
2023-01-02 15:37:54.777  WARN 122623 --- [nio-8090-exec-7] .m.m.a.ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver : Resolved [org.springframework.orm.ObjectOptimisticLockingFailureException: Batch update returned unexpected row count from update [0]; actual row count: 0; expected: 1; statement executed: update my_model set field1=? where id=? and version=?;
```

can't we execute the partial update by non-primary key?

Comment: make sure after mapstruct data override your entity have same uuid value. can you please debug and check whether before and after UUID value remains same or not.

Comment: I found the issue, the UUID is in binary format. I added this `@Type(type = "org.hibernate.type.UUIDCharType")` annotation before my Id. Now it works fine.